# Stop ARM GCC Optimising Out Function Call

Tags: gcc, arm

```
volatile static const uint8_t mcau8IsBlank[] = {0xFF}; // Value in MCU FLASH memory
// The above value may actually be modified by a FLASH Write elsewhere in the code

bool halIsBlank() {
  return ((*(uint8_t*)mcau8IsBlank));
}

void someFuncInAnotherFile() {
  uint8_t data[64];
  data[0] = halIsBlank();  // ARM GCC is optimising away this function call
                           // Replacing it simply with a 0xFF constant
  // ... etc
  // ... transmit data
}
```

How do I get ARM GCC to not optimise out the call to `halIsBlank()`? The compiler is assuming that `mcau8IsBlank[]` is always `== 0xFF` and is thus simply replacing the call with a `0xFF` constant.

I can disable optimisation of the calling function (`someFuncInAnotherFile()`) by adding `__attribute__((optimize(0)))` to it, but it would be better to add some attribute to the called function  (`halIsBlank()`) (and no attributes or keywords that I've tried seem to do the trick)?

Comment: Declaring the const as volatile apparently results in it not being placed in FLASH anymore but rather in RAM. For now I've resorted to exposing the const outside of the file and using it directly, rather than using the function call.

Comment: If it is in flash then it is a constant and can be optimized away (define it in an other file and it might at least do the access even if in flash).

Comment: put it in its own file as if it were global data but link it in the flash.

Comment: the static doesnt make much sense either.

Answer (score 0):

If an object is declared as const then any attempt to modify it leads to undefined behaviour. The compiler is allowed to assume that a const object is constant. And you explictely cast away the volatileness of the array, so the compiler can assume it is not volatile at this point.

I'd remove that cast to (uint8_t *) which seems to be pointless anyway.

Answer (score 0):

so.c

```
const unsigned char one = 0x11;
unsigned char two = 0x22;
volatile unsigned char three = 0x33;
extern unsigned char four;
unsigned int get_one ( void )
{
    return(one);
}
unsigned int get_two ( void )
{
    return(two);
}
unsigned int get_three ( void )
{
    return(three);
}
unsigned int get_four ( void )
{
    return(four);
}
```

four.c

```
unsigned char four = 0x44;
```

gnu ld linker script

```
MEMORY
{
    rom : ORIGIN = 0x10000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
    ram : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
}
SECTIONS
{
    .text   : { *(.text*)
                four.o(.data)       } > rom
    .rodata : { *(.rodata*) } > rom
    .data   : { *(.data*)   } > ram
}
```

result

```
Disassembly of section .text:

10000000 <_start>:
10000000:   20001000    andcs   r1, r0, r0
10000004:   10000009    andne   r0, r0, r9

10000008 <reset>:
10000008:   e7fe        b.n 10000008 <reset>
    ...

1000000c <get_one>:
1000000c:   2011        movs    r0, #17
1000000e:   4770        bx  lr

10000010 <get_two>:
10000010:   4b01        ldr r3, [pc, #4]    ; (10000018 <get_two+0x8>)
10000012:   7818        ldrb    r0, [r3, #0]
10000014:   4770        bx  lr
10000016:   bf00        nop
10000018:   20000000    andcs   r0, r0, r0

1000001c <get_three>:
1000001c:   4b01        ldr r3, [pc, #4]    ; (10000024 <get_three+0x8>)
1000001e:   7858        ldrb    r0, [r3, #1]
10000020:   4770        bx  lr
10000022:   bf00        nop
10000024:   20000000    andcs   r0, r0, r0

10000028 <get_four>:
10000028:   4b01        ldr r3, [pc, #4]    ; (10000030 <get_four+0x8>)
1000002a:   7818        ldrb    r0, [r3, #0]
1000002c:   4770        bx  lr
1000002e:   bf00        nop
10000030:   10000034    andne   r0, r0, r4, lsr r0

10000034 <four>:
10000034:   Address 0x0000000010000034 is out of bounds.


Disassembly of section .rodata:

10000035 <one>:
10000035:   Address 0x0000000010000035 is out of bounds.


Disassembly of section .data:

20000000 <two>:
20000000:   Address 0x0000000020000000 is out of bounds.


20000001 <three>:
20000001:   Address 0x0000000020000001 is out of bounds.
```

Because one is const the local function optimizes, but it is also global so added to flash (in case other objects reference it).  Make it static and the allocation in flash goes away.

Two is plain old .data.  Has to build the code this way, linker adds the address at link time.

Three is volatile global handled the same way as two because it was global and in .data, volatile does not do much here.

Four is a solution if you choose.  Define it outside this file/optimization domain, and the compiler has to generate code to reach an unknown length to get it.  In the linker script tell the linker to place it in flash.  So while it is in flash and technically not read/write, if you have a way to write the flash then this will work.

Well actually it will not because when you erase the flash to change four you wipe out some percentage of this .text code along with it. You need to know the part what the erase blocks are and put things like these in one of those erase blocks, and you have to save all of them to ram if you want to change one of them, save all, erase, write back all including any changed values...And rare that you can execute in the same flash logic as the flash being erased so may need a trampoline to do this save, erase, restore routine.  (more linker magic and a copy and jump)

One function calling another in the same optimization domain is going to likely inline it so you will want to find a please do not inline command line option, although for this case that does not make any sense, you want to optimize and possibly make the small function static so it goes away all together.

Comment: you can try to pragma your way through this making the variable in another section then adding that section to the linker script to control where it lands.  But you asked for const and const means no changes so volatile is useless and the optimizer will optimize out a const access it can see.  the too did what you asked.

Comment: Thanks! Using the linker script is possibly the best solution. The variable/const is originally declared as 0xFF and bits are only ever cleared by writing, so no FLASH erase takes place.

Comment: Please take care with your spellings here, especially words containing apostrophes. Here are some correct spellings, plus the number of mispellings in your post history: don't (765), doesn't (488), can't (306), won't (217), isn't (148). There is some tolerance here for people who don't have English as a first language, but stylistic and deliberate misspelling works against the aims of the site, and is a great deal of work being deliberately made for volunteer editors. Do you have a spell-checker available in your browser?